# How to get query string on search page in shopify

Tags: shopify, query-string

I have a shopify store. I am passing new parameters on search page using query string anyone tell me how can i get this new query string on search page

Comment: Ideally when you do a search in a shopify website you get to the search page with the seach parameter in the query. For example if you search "abc" in the website you will be redirected to https://<yourdomain>/search?q=abc. You should be able to get the query parameter

Comment: yes q is default parameters but i want to add more param in query string

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: https://sitename/search?q=abc&sort_by=price-ascending so in this url i want to get sort_by value

Comment: When the search button is clicked write a function which will ignore any events attached to the button and pass the parameter to the search page url. `function(ev){ev.preventDefault; s_url += "new_param=new_value";}`

Comment: i already pass this param to url i want to get this value in liquid file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can't get new parameters outside the default ones using liquid. Liquid is now aware of additional query parameters.

If you **really really** have to take them in liquid then you will have a hacky option to capture the `content_for_header` argument and you can extract the arguments from there ( since there is a URL with the query params there ) with a few splits. You will need to look for the `pageurl` string there. But like I said this is a hacky way which should be used as a last resort.